# Codeigniter active record join with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I have 3 tables,

```
user - contains user_id | username | fullname | email etcc
user_profile - contains entry_id |user_id| profile_image_id| user_location etcc
user_profile_images - contains image_id| user_id | file_path | file_thumb | date etcc
```

When a user sign's up, all the details go to the users table, the user_id is also added to the user_profile table with the rest set default as NULL till the user add's some profile info.

I have a query in model_users to get all user's data from these three table and it goes like this;

```
$this->db->where('users.user_id', $user_id)->select('*')->from('users');
$this->db->join('user_profile', 'user_profile.user_id = users.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('user_profile_images','user_profile_images.image_id = user_profile.profile_image_id','left');
```

It work's fine only when the profile_image_id field in user_profile is not null, that is  when the user has uploaded a pic. In the case where the field is null, the user user_id is not returned even when all the other data are returned.

I can see why this is the case, as my join query requires the field profile_image_id but currently my way around it was to set profile_image_id in user_profile as 1(default), which is the default image and has image_id as 1 and user_id as 0 as it's the general default image. But i still can't get over the fact that i need to update that query to make it less of a hack.
Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: try changing the user_profile_images join to a 'right' join?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it still didn't work :(

Comment: Your best bet is to close this question, turn the query into a raw MySQL query, then post that query here on SO. There are alot of mySQL experts here - but I doubt they will know the answer to this question in its current format.

Comment: just do not use **left** and change this **user_profile_images.image_id = user_profile.profile_image_id** to this **user_profile.profile_image_id = user_profile_images.image_id**  then check if you have index setted also

Comment: @Ispuk Why would a left join be a problem? Actually left joins normally gets the fastest performance for join syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$this->db->select('*')->select('users.user_id')->from('users')
                ->join('user_profile', 'user_profile.user_id = users.user_id', 'LEFT')
                ->join('user_profile_images', 'user_profile_images.image_id = user_profile.profile_image_id', 'LEFT')
                ->group_by('users.user_id')
                ->where('users.user_id', $user_id);
                $query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

When using join for tables you need your columns in all joined tables to have unique names. Either you add column aliases by AS syntax or just retrieve the columns you need. In your case the error is most probably due to the fact that `user_id` exists in all three tables. Hence the result is like you experience. `user_id` is retrieved only for the last occurrence and that is if your user has uploaded an image. I would alter the query someting like:

```
$this->db->where('users.user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->select('users.*,user_profile.user_location,user_profile_images.filepath'); // and other fields of interest...
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->group_by('users.user_id'); // very useful for not getting multiple rows/user
$this->db->join('user_profile', 'user_profile.user_id = users.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('user_profile_images','user_profile_images.image_id = user_profile.profile_image_id','left');
```

Comment: Thanks jtheman, they are quite a lot of fields so i won't be able to select them manually :(  In the mean time i used a double select(->select('*')->select('users.user_id') ). Which worked but do you think that's good coding practice?

Comment: No problem having double selects however you could put it in just one with a comma (select('*,users.user_id') ). I would not do the select on '*' though as it returns duplicate columns...

Answer (score 0):

Try This one.

```
 $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->from('table1');
            $this->db->join('table2','table2.id1=table1.id1');
            $this->db->join('table3','table3.id1=table1.id1');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
```